# Google Sheets conditional formatting gradient not applied for values >= 1 and < 2

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a Google sheet where several columns use a gradient (using traffic light colours - from red to yellow to green) to indicate values from min to max.

This works fine for values less than one, and for values of two or greater, but for some reason values between 1 and 2 just show up as white. I can't see any reason why this might be.

Here is the conditional formatting I have applied:

[image: Conditional formatting panel]

And here is an example of what it looks like when applied to the spreadsheet:

[image: 3 columns with conditional formatting applied]

This seems completely nonsensical to me. The settings are very simple, but they just don't seem to work.

NB I have tried removing the midpoint, and have also tried changing from percentage to min/max values, but neither of these helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that all the cells with `bold text` formatting remain white.
Do you also have another conditional formatting set on the same cells?  If yes, put it second in the list of conditional formatting for that range.

[image]

Comment: Ah, that's it! Thank you so much  not just a formula, a mis-written one - it was only supposed to highlight Mondays in bold, and TBH I'd forgotten that I'd even added it. If it had been working as intended then this would have been a lot easier to diagnose!